# What do Klingon ears look like?

Tags: star-trek

Except pre-retcon TOS-era Klingons, I don't think I've ever seen their ears. They always seems to be covered by their hair.

[image]

At least, I assume they still have ears...?

Comment: we do know this,. they don't have points like Vulcans or Romulans. when Worf was about to make out with that young Klingon he was shocked when she had pointed ears.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They appear to be pretty much the same as human ears in location, shape and size.

I searched on 'bald Klingon' to find [Chang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang_%28Star_Trek%29) ([Christopher Plummer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Plummer)).

[image: Chang - with ears]

Comment: ..it would have been more interesting if a bald Klingon could at least grow a mustache and *the fur on his ears*.  But given the actor asked for the head adornments to be downplayed, I doubt they'd have had the courage to ask him to wear furry ears.  ;)

Comment: Also Chancellor [Gorkon](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110117002314/memoryalpha/en/images/0/0f/Gorkon.jpg), officer [Maltz](http://www.startrek.com/uploads/assets/db_articles/24ac28e029c3b50c11dfc502764cfd2287afd69e.jpg), and the [Ambassador](http://www.startrek.com/legacy_media/images/200508/mov-006-klingon-ambassador02/320x240.jpg) from ST IV all seem to have their ears where you'd expect them.